# How to store $_Post values separated by &

Tags: php

I did

```
file_put_contents("x.txt", print_r($_POST, true));
```

And I got the below output

```
Array
    (
        [merchant_id] => ece6ba4ecx24d070b4c13b
        [invoice_id] => 1772fb6eafda04ceb11c77cf719a347f
        [invoice_created] => 1634467789
        [invoice_expires] => 1634469589
        [invoice_amount] => 10
    )
```

How do I store `$_POST` values only (not keys) separated by & in form of a string like the one below:

Will this work

```
echo implode("&",$_POST);
```

Output example:

```
ece6ba4ec435986db93924d070b4c13b&1772fb6eafda04ceb11c77cf719a347f&1634467789&1634469589&10
```

Comment: `implode('&', array_values($_POST))`

Comment: I would recommend storing in a more robust format such as JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [implode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) and set `&` as the separator:

```
$string = implode('&', $_POST);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in function of **PHP** **array_values()** to get only the values from the $_POST array.
Then, use the built in function **implode**, to combine the whole array into one string seprated by & sign.

```
$values = array_values($_POST);
$string_values = implode("&",$values);
```

Comment: `implode()` only uses the values so there's no need for `array_values()`